# winforms - tooltip of statusbar labels not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, statusbaritem

I have a couple of labels in status bar, on which I have set tooltip.

```
statusLblWeek.Text = weeklyHrs.ToString();
statusLblWeek.ToolTipText = " Consumption of this week " + statusLblWeek.Text;
```

Status labels are displayed correctly but the tooltip is not showing up. Why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use property [StatusStrip.ShowItemToolTips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.statusstrip.showitemtooltips.aspx)

True if ToolTips are shown for the StatusStrip; otherwise, false. The default is false.

```
statusStrip1.ShowItemToolTips = true;
statusLblWeek.Text = weeklyHrs.ToString();
statusLblWeek.ToolTipText = " Consumption of this week " + statusLblWeek.Text;
```