# ToolTip does not show in Status bar addin

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, statusbar

I am developing a status bar Add-in for a business program. The add-in returns a usercontrol that is placed on the statusbar by the program. In that User Control I have a small icon in a picturebox. I want to show a tooltip when the user hovers over the icon.
I have the following code:

```
ToolTip Message = new ToolTip();
Message .ShowAlways = true;
Message.SetToolTip(MyIcon);
```

The Tooltip does not show up however. This is probably due to  the [StatusStrip.ShowItemToolTips set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427339/winforms-tooltip-of-statusbar-labels-not-showing-up). I cannot change this however since that is part of the program.

Is there any way to force the tooltips to show, or can I inherit a custom class from the ToolTip class and have it show up? I do not want to create a complete new class for something that is already there.

Comment: Use the picture box' MouseHover event, call Message.Show().

Comment: Hey Hans, you mean Messagebox? Having users hover over an item and popping up a messagebox will not let them have great thoughts about my products...

Comment: No, you named your tooltip "Message" for some reason.  Fake code?  Nice.

Comment: aaa! Not sure how I did not see that! Thanks for the suggestion it works great. I did remove the Showalways & SetTooltip, since that was causing strange behavior. Now it is all great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Hans Passant's Suggestion I ended up with the following;

```
ToolTip Message = new ToolTip();
MyIcon.MouseHover += ShowToolTip;

private void ShowToolTip(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message.Show("Bladiebla",MyIcon);
    }
```